# css media queries weird behavior

Tags: css, media-queries

Im building a responsive website using media queries.

Relevant code:

```
.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 2%;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding-top: 2.5em;
}
```

When I downsize my browser, the elements on the page become bigger than the container element, because of the padding. When I set the padding manually to 0 with the developer tools of chrome, the elements are fitting perfectly again in the container (just as I want it).

So I thought, I make a media query for it and reset the padding to 0 when the elements become bigger than the container.

Like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 966px) {
    .container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    }
}
```

Chrome applies the code perfectly (it does not get overridden), however the elements still are larger than the container. I dont know why this is happening, it is really weird.

Comment: Can you make an example in [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but I figured it out myself.

I fixed it by overriding the row class from bootstrap (which sets both to -15), which was the REAL problem(fix).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 966px) {
    .row {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

I cant answer my question yet, so if a moderator wants to do it, go ahead. Its solved.

Comment: new people have to wait 8 hours before answering their own questions. I dont know why, so i answered it today instead of yesterday.

Comment: Well, you can probably remove that statement now that you've posted an answer. (You can also mark it accepted - in another day or so.)

Answer (score 0):

In your media query you set your margin and padding to "auto," and "0." I think you may want to define all four of the properties:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 966px) {
.container {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding-top: 2.5em;
}
}
```

Properties are carried over if the media query don't overwrite them.